# Binary search Java program to find a key but it is not showing any output over Terminal

Tags: java, binary-search

I coded this binary search program for finding a key but it does not show any output in the terminal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqcse.png)

```
import java.util.\*;
public class BinarySearch {
public static int binarySearch(int number\[\], int key) {
int start = 0, end = number.length-1;
while (start\<=end) {
int mid = (start+end)/2;

            //comparisons
            if (number[mid] == key) { //found
                return mid;
            }
            if (number[mid] < key) { //right
                start = mid+1;
            }
            else {  //left
                start = mid-1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numbers[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14};
        int key = 10;
        System.out.println("index for key is " + binarySearch(numbers, key));
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to have inserted a load of backslashes in your code, making it unrunnable. I suggest you [edit] your question and fix it.

Comment: This can be easily solved by using a debugger.

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on `int start` and use a debugging process.  Use `Step Over`, or key `F8`, to go to the next line.